# Werewolf romance book where female had to fight werewolf to keep her position in the pack

Tags: story-identification, books, werewolf

I am trying to find this book where a female had to fight a werewolf in order to keep her position in pack and her mate can’t help her. She ends up shooting the wolf and winning the challenge.  I think she had to be converted to a werewolf in order to live after the challenge.

Comment: That plot describes a fair amount of werewolf romance fiction.  Please check out https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info to elicit further details.

Comment: Is she a skinwalker? Are there vampires? Are there fey? What color is her hair?

Comment: If you're trying to edit your question, you should probably register an account, and then get your accounts [merged](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Otherwise, we can't tell that it's you, and may not approve the edit.

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score -1):

I read one called [Scarlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarlet_(novel)), where that was pretty close to one part of the story, but I'm sure many others are similar.

> Scarlet Benoit is a young girl living on her grandmother's farm in Rieux, France. Her grandmother has gone missing for many weeks and Scarlet is sure that she has been kidnapped rather than left on her own will as the authorities believe. While delivering fresh goods to one of her loyal but unfriendly customers, her friend Emilié introduces her to a jittery shy street fighter whose code name is Wolf, who saves her after she makes a speech defending Linh Cinder, the Lunar cyborg who caused chaos at the Eastern Commonwealth ball. She notices a tattoo on his arm; a string of numbers and letters that have no meaning to her. When she gets back from her job, her estranged dad is there and is desperately trying to find something. She questions her dad, who has burn marks all up his arms from being tortured, and he says that the same people have her grandmother because she is hiding something. The one clue that he can remember is that the kidnappers had a tattoo on their forearm, similar to Wolf's. Scarlet heads out to question Wolf in a fight ring, where he defeats and almost kills the champion. The next morning Wolf comes by her farm and tells her that the tattoo stands for a group he used to be part of and that they are the ones who kidnapped her grandma. He decides to help Scarlet and they both embark on a trip to Paris.
>
> On the train to Paris, Scarlet meets a man called Ran, who Wolf seems to smell on her later. They jump off the train after a letumosis outbreak occurs and continue their journey through the woods. While resting, Ran shows up and Scarlet realizes that he and Wolf already know each other and don't get along well, and Ran is eventually revealed to be Wolf's younger brother. Wolf fights with Ran and almost kills him until Scarlet shoots him in the arm. They leave Ran unconscious and get on another train to Paris, and Scarlet learns that her father has died. Throughout this time, Wolf and Scarlet start to develop romantic feelings for each other.

Comment: As I said on your previous post could you try and edit to explain why this is correct.,